# How to add a preprocess function in Omega theme?

Tags: views, theming

Omega theme has a singular way to add preprocess functions.

I need to add this preprocess function to be executed when a view is rendered:

```
function MyTheme_alpha_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
...
}
```

This is what I've done (is not working, the dpm function doesn't print the message, no error is shown)

1) In `sites/all/themes/MyTheme/preprocess/`created the file `preprocess-views-view-fields.inc`

2) In `preprocess-views-view-fields.inc` I added the function:

```
   function MyTheme_alpha_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
     dpm('hello');
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Standard question: Have you cleared the cache since adding the file and adding the new preprocess hook?

Comment: @Jimajamma  Omega lets you split out preprocess and process functions into separate include files.  The base theme itself scans/includes/invokes them, and part of this is a slightly different naming convention to avoid clashes with putting the functions directly in template.php.

Comment: @clive: I cleared cache several times.

Comment: you put this function like this template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) in your template.php

Comment: I think that the problem is that I have Aggregation enabled in the view...

Comment: @Sathiya: is not working.

Comment: does dpr() work?